# Why does MySQL is slower if I don't specify an index

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize a SQL query and I'm wondering how to do so appropriately.

```sql
SELECT 
    r0_.*
FROM ride r0_ use index (ride_booking_id_IDX)
LEFT JOIN booking b1_ ON r0_.booking_id = b1_.id 
LEFT JOIN spot s2_ ON r0_.from_spot_id = s2_.id 
LEFT JOIN spot s3_ ON r0_.to_spot_id = s3_.id 
WHERE b1_.start_at <= '2023-04-21' 
    AND b1_.end_at >= '2023-04-20' 
    AND b1_.paid_at IS NOT NULL 
    AND b1_.cancelled_at IS NULL 
    AND ((s2_.zone_id = 1 OR s3_.zone_id = 1)) 
    AND s2_.type = 'parking';
```

Here I force the use of my index `(booking_id, from_spot_id, to_spot_id)` which leads query to execute in around 100ms for recent date against 25 seconds !

`booking` table has approx 2 millions rows while `ride` table has approx 5 millions rows.

However, I can see it scan way more rows with the forced index :

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | b1_ |  | range | PRIMARY,booking_id_end_IDX,booking_id_IDX,booking_id_start_IDX,IDX_E00CEDDEB75363F7,IDX_E00CEDDE37D3107C,IDX_E00CEDDEDEA4208C,booking_paid_at_IDX,booking_cancelled_at_IDX | IDX_E00CEDDE37D3107C | 6 |  | 111456 | 6.6 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | r0_ |  | ref | ride_booking_id_IDX | ride_booking_id_IDX | 109 | ector.b1_.id | 1 | 100.0 |  |
| 1 | SIMPLE | s2_ |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,IDX_B9327A739F2C3FAB,spot_type_IDX | PRIMARY | 4 | ector.r0_.from_spot_id | 1 | 72.52 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | s3_ |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | ector.r0_.to_spot_id | 1 | 100.0 | Using where |

Versus the same query without the use index :

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | s2_ |  | ref | PRIMARY,IDX_B9327A739F2C3FAB,spot_type_IDX | spot_type_IDX | 767 | const | 161 | 100.0 | Using index condition |
| 1 | SIMPLE | r0_ |  | ref | IDX_9B3D7CD0ABAF30D3,IDX_9B3D7CD03301C60,ride_booking_id_IDX,booking_from_spot_to_spot_IDX | IDX_9B3D7CD0ABAF30D3 | 5 | ector.s2_.id | 392 | 100.0 |  |
| 1 | SIMPLE | b1_ |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,booking_id_end_IDX,booking_id_IDX,booking_id_start_IDX,IDX_E00CEDDEB75363F7,IDX_E00CEDDE37D3107C,IDX_E00CEDDEDEA4208C,booking_paid_at_IDX,booking_cancelled_at_IDX | PRIMARY | 108 | ector.r0_.booking_id | 1 | 5.0 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | s3_ |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | ector.r0_.to_spot_id | 1 | 100.0 | Using where |

I understand that the dates I used to compare with `start_at` and `end_at` is the reason why the query is significantly faster.

I therefore tried to isolate the slowest part to a smaller query :

`SELECT * from booking b where b.start_at < '2021-01-01' and b.end_at > '2021-01-01';`

On the table booking, I have two index `(start_at)` and `(end_at)` that helps this query run faster when you're close to the max and min values (since the index will filter most rows, there's few left to scan).

However, when I take a random value sufficiently far away in the past, it becomes way slower. The query above runs in 10 seconds because it only uses one of the two index as expected and I don't know why the explain does not show a merge_index on such a simple query :

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | b |  | range | IDX_E00CEDDEB75363F7,IDX_E00CEDDE37D3107C | IDX_E00CEDDEB75363F7 | 6 |  | 1147319 | 50 | Using index condition; Using where |

As I can't have an index satisfying both range conditions, I tried to split the query in half

```sql
SELECT * from booking b
INNER JOIN booking b2 use index(booking_id_start_IDX)  ON b.id = b2.id and b2.start_at < '2021-01-01'
INNER JOIN booking b3 use index(booking_id_end_IDX) ON b.id = b3.id and b3.end_at > '2021-01-01';
```

This query runs significantly faster in about 600ms. However, due to the simplicity of the query and the fact it returns approximately 7k rows, I expected it to be in two digits at most.

I don't understand why the query isn't automatically picking my index `(id, start_at)` and `(id, end_at)` ? What am I missing ?

I know I could partition my table to get better result but I have foreign keys I can't drop so it's not a solution. Should I think of another architecture and have a table keeping the reservation dates alone without any foreign key in it and let booking table refer to it so I can partition the reservation table ? Will it be feasible to have a foreign key in booking referring to the partitioned reservation table ?

Mysql engine is running in AWS with the following version : 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.02.2

Output of `SELECT @@optimizer_switch` is :

`index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on,use_invisible_indexes=off,skip_scan=on,hash_join=on,subquery_to_derived=off,prefer_ordering_index=on,hypergraph_optimizer=off,derived_condition_pushdown=on`

Comment: The MySQL query optimizer is not the best in the business.

Comment: Using LEFT JOIN and then filtering the right side table with a WHERE clause, results in an INNER JOIN...

Comment: Do your bookings have a maximum duration? If so you can put an additional constraint on the start and end dates. (start >= date - maxduration AND start < date), etc.

Comment: For the booking, I agree that inner join is better, for spot, it's not so obvious as we use a OR, with an inner join, we would lose rows.

Bookings have a way too long maximum duration and I prefer not to put that in database constraints as it's subject to change and might depends on the zone of the booking.

Comment: You are ***already*** potentially losing rows due to `AND s2_.type = 'parking'` in the `WHERE` clause.  The `WHERE` clause is only asserted ***after*** the joins; as such, any input row that doesn't have a matching row in `s2_` will have `AND null = 'parking'` which is not true, and so filtered out.  It *sounds like* you should move that condition in to the join predicate, because at the moment it is behaving as an `INNER JOIN`, even though you wrote it as a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: If I move `type` comparison to the join clause, the query would give me more results which I don't want. Basically, the query only grab rides targeting a `parking` spot. If I move the `parking` condition to the join clause, because of the `OR` made on `zone_id`, the query would bring every rides that are either coming from zone 1 or rides that are going to a parking in zone 1. I want all rides that are targeting a parking and that are either starting or ending in zone 1. There's a subtle difference here

Answer (score 0):

Your index `(id, start_at)` isn't being picked because there's no fixed `id`s to search for.

Depending on your use case, you might need to create an index on `start_at` and another on `end_at`. After that a simple query as `SELECT * from booking b where b.start_at < '2021-01-01' and b.end_at > '2021-01-01';` will work right away; depending on the search criteria MySQL might use one index or both through a `MERGE INDEX` optimized operation.

In case you prefer to have a single index, you'll need to carefully pick the order of the fields, as indexes are used on the same order they are defined.

Edit: after OPs edit, here's my thought.

> On the table booking, I have two index (`start_at`) and (`end_at`) that helps this query run faster when you're close to the max and min values (since the index will filter most rows, there's few left to scan).

This explains things rather good. Given you're `SELECT *`, MySQL is forced to read the whole table. Try selecting `id` only and in that case it will most likely use the index; as it would be an index-covered query.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I also have a `start_at` and `end_at` index alone for this query. However, as expected, only one is used hence why it's very slow if both index split data in two. I updated my original answer to provide more detail in this regard including the explain on this query. Curiously, MySQL does not try to perform a `MERGE INDEX`

Comment: I'd say then to share the indices you have.